# How to get size of zip file before save to disk by using Ionic.Zip.ZipFile?

Tags: c#, zip

I am usig Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.I want to create 10 mb zip file.I need get size of ZipFile before save to disk.Is it possible ?

```
    private static string tempPath = "@Temp Folder";
    List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();


    using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zf = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Count; i++)
      {
        zf.AddFile(tempPath + fileNames[i], string.Empty);

        //How can I get size of zf before save here ?

      if(zf size==10mb)
      {

       zf.Save(tempPath + string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}.zip","XXX", "XXX", 
          DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
      }

     }
   }
```

Comment: It will almost never be `== 10mb`. You'll have to specify this in how much under or overshoot you can tolerate.

Comment: The desired solution is not totally clear, do you want to stop writing or create multiple zip files?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have 10000 pdf files in temp folder.I want to create  multiple zip file from this folder.Zip file's size will be maximum 10 mb.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your zip into a `MemoryStream`:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
zip.Save(ms);
```

then read the [MemoryStream.Length Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.length(v=vs.110).aspx) and get the size.

If you then still want to save it to disk just use the memory stream you already have:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("file.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
// I believe you'll need to rewind the stream before saving
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
ms.WriteTo(file);
file.Close();
ms.Close();
```